# List of my own questions

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

In the Stack Exchange iOS app, there doesn't seem to be any way to list your own questions.  You can potentially see some in your activity list but they may show along side other questions that you viewed or commented/answered on, not necessarily that they're your own.  On the website version of Stack Exchange you can find a list of your questions under your profile, but that too seems to be missing from the iOS app.

Am I missing something?

Comment: All your questions networkwide or just on a specific site?

Comment: @Glorfindel Either would be fine. I'd prefer the former but the latter would work, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all your questions on a single site, go to the question list and search for `user:me is:q`:

[image]

There is no specific button for this, nor is there currently a network-wide list of your questions in the app, but that's what a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is for!

Comment: Nice. So, there's no button or area to do this without having to remember some search query, like there is on the website?

Comment: So, since I tagged this as feature-request when I asked, it's been requested?

Comment: Those buttons do not exist and the development of the app is kinda frozen right now. Posting a feature request is the right action.

Comment: @JesseP. You can view your own profile and click the "All n posts" which takes you to all of your posts and then add the is:q if that's easier.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh. I see.  So, where do we go from here?

Comment: @Catija right, that works too. Less typing, more tapping :)

Comment: @Catija That's effectively the same as what Glorfindel said but it still seems much more cumbersome than it should be, especially since there is the functionality in the website for this, without the need for manual entering a search string.  Seems like a pretty basic feature that was not thought of when building the app.